# Regexp to match words in a string, while also matching strings between quotes

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm having trouble figuring this out. I'll admit i suck at regex, but here's the basic idea:

Let's say you have the string

```
word "two words" word2
```

How would i get a regex together to match 'word' and 'word2', and at the same time match 'two words' as it's own match?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use something like this:

```
((\w+)|"([ \w]+)")
```

Here is a regex101:
https://regex101.com/r/eT7CdJ/1

Comment: You may consider making that second `+`  a non-gready one in case there is more than one string!

Comment: @ibrahimmahrir thank you for the comment, check this example: https://regex101.com/r/eT7CdJ/3

Comment: Is there a way to remove the quotes with the regex, or should i just do a replace on those?

Comment: @DaveSiegel: The subgroup between the quotes gives you that content.

Comment: I think you can actually drop that outer group. Or at least making it non-capturing would be good.